# Using a User control as dynamic control (may be a literal control) in C# asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have a user control which is an image button.
I want that control to be dynamically added "n" times in my webpage.
"n" comes from the database.
I tried this code:
in "aspx":

```
   <%@ Register TagPrefix="uc" TagName="imgbtn"         Src="~/components/seatfromdb/usercontrol/UC_imgbutton.ascx" %>
.........................................
    //some code goes here
.......................................
     <uc:imgbtn ID="uc_imgbtn"
                runat="server"
                />
```

in "cs":

```
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
     UserControl uc = new UserControl();
               uc = uc_imgbtn;
                //uc.Attributes.Keys = "~/images/buttonorange.png";
                //uc.ID = "uc" + i.ToString();
                //uc.Height = 30;
                plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(uc);
                plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
 }
```

But the control "uc" added to the page only one time. Why?
Please help me with this code.

Comment: What's `uc_imgbtn` in C#?

Comment: I have edited my question. Please take a look at it

Comment: @artm Id of ImageBtn, a User Control

Comment: I see. Instead of adding imgbtn 5 times, create a new `UC_imgbutton` and add this new control.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not create `UserControl`, call `Page.LoadControl` method to get a new instance of `UC_imgbutton`.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
  UC_imgbutton uc = (UC_imgbutton)LoadControl("~/components/seatfromdb/usercontrol/UC_imgbutton.ascx");
  //uc.Attributes.Keys = "~/images/buttonorange.png";
  //uc.ID = "uc" + i.ToString();
  //uc.Height = 30;
  plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(uc);
  plhdr_seat.Controls.Add(new LiteralControl("<br />"));
}
```

Comment: LoadControl is not highlighted. Reference missing. I have System.Web.UI. But still something missing.

Comment: They must have banned you from Google - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.loadcontrol(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

This happens because you are always assigning `uc_imgbtn` to your `new UserControl();`. In other words you are always assign the same existing control to the `plhdr_seat.Controls` collection.

Check the **Note** at [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.controlcollection.add(v=vs.110).aspx) for more details:

> A Control can only be assigned to one Control.ControlCollection at a
>   time. If the Control is already a child of another control it is
>   removed from that control before it is added to another control.

If you want to add a new `uc_imgbtn` control every time to the `plhdr_seat.Controls` collection you should change your code to:

```
UserControl uc = new UserControl(); // change this
uc = uc_imgbtn; // remove this
```

In the first line you must make sure sure you properly initialize the `uc` control. As far as I can see from your code, this should work: `imgbtn uc = new imgbtn();`

Comment: imgbtn uc = new imgbtn(); not working. imgbtn is tagname